# Println prints square brackets but interface is not a slice

Tags: go

I'm having a strange problem with interfaces, when I try to print a value Println adds square brackets. I believe this is because that interface contains slices, but I'm not sure how should iterate them.

I'm quite sure it's a newbie question but I spend alot time searching for a clue and can't find any.

Also I couldn't reproduce it without using goes, so here's the code that I actually used:

```
package main


import "fmt"
import "github.com/belogik/goes"
import "net/url"

func getConnection() (conn *goes.Connection) {
    conn = goes.NewConnection("localhost", "9200")

    return
}

func main() {

    conn := getConnection()
    var query = map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "bool": map[string]interface{}{
                "must": map[string]interface{}{
                    "match_all": map[string]interface{}{},
                },
            },
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 3,
        "fields": []string{"name"},
    }
    extraArgs := make(url.Values)
    searchResults, err := conn.Search(query, []string{"myindex"}, []string{"mytype"}, extraArgs)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result := searchResults.Hits.Hits

    for _,element := range result {
        name := element.Fields["name"]
        fmt.Println( name )
        fmt.Printf( "%#v\n", name )
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
[One]
[]interface {}{"One"}
[Two]
[]interface {}{"Two"}
[Three]
[]interface {}{"Three"}
```

However if I try to loop over the "name" like so:

```
for _, e := range name {
    fmt.Println( e )
}
```

I'm getting "cannot range over name (type interface {})"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a type assertion. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]interface{}{}
    m["name"] = []interface{}{"One"}
    fmt.Println(m)

    name := m["name"]
    fmt.Println(name)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", name)

    for _, e := range name.([]interface{}) {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
map[name:[One]]
[One]
[]interface {}{"One"}
One
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)
>
> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now, also `name.([]interface{})[0]` gives me what I want as I don't care about other values.

Comment: @PokazC keep in mind that if the slice is empty, that will cause a runtime panic.